# How to download a video directly from a url using python?

Tags: python, video

I am new to python and I want to download a video from a given URL. So 
far I've heard about `urllib`, `urllib2` and `requests` modules that help to download a video from URL, but when I tried them I apparently got all the data on that
page and I don't know what I got, or even if the video is in there since the size of the output file is usually 50-170 KB and videos are usually way more than that. I'll post two codes of mine that are meant to download a video so you can tell me if they have any problem. If they are okay, can you tell me how to separate the video from what I got or if the video is even there?

1.

```
import requests

def download_file(url):
 local_filename = url.split('/')[-1]

 r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
 with open("D://"+local_filename, 'wb') as f:
    for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
        if chunk: 
            f.write(chunk)

earl = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DBYjZTdrJlA"
download_file(earl)
```

2.

```
 import urllib2
 import os


 earl="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DBYjZTdrJlA"
 y= True
 try: response=urllib2.urlopen(earl)
 except urllib2.HTTPError:
  print "oopsy, website wont allow it"
  y=False


 def downloader(url):
   response=urllib2.urlopen(url)
   info = response.read()
   print info
   fx= open(os.path.join("D://", "video.mp4"),'wb')
   for line in info:
     fx.write(line)
   fx.close()
   print "done"

  if(y):
  downloader(earl)
```

Comment: You can try to use youtube-dl module
https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/

Comment: thanks but I would like to download videos from any site

Comment: youtube-dl is compatible with a lot of site (https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/tree/master/youtube_dl/extractor).
 Without youtube-dl you need to parse each site you visit to get the correct video url. And then you can dll it with python request or urllib2

Answer (score 0):

That is because you must have an url finishing in **.mp4**. If you don't have that, requests will process and download the page that you see when entering to the YouTube url.

You con try other modules like *youtube-dl* ([youtube-dl from pypi](https://pypi.org/project/youtube_dl/)) or you can try (I don't know if that is possible) to scrape the data of the YouTube url page for extracting the url of the video.

Comment: But how can we download https://salam.alphaschool.ir/cyx67gkabj5d/iframe ?